# Is every connected reductive group over a local field already defined over a global field?

Tags: reductive-groups, local-fields

Let $K$ be a local field, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or $\mathbb{F}_p((t))$. Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $K$. Is it true that $G$ is already defined over a global field? More precisely, does there exist a global field $F$, a place $v$ in $F$ with $F_v\simeq K$ and a connected reductive group $\tilde{G}$ over $F$ such that as groups
$$\tilde{G}\otimes_F F_v\simeq G?$$
I am particularly interested in the case where $K$ is of equal characteristic. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The connected reductive group is defined by some equations with coefficients in your local field. Take a global field dense in your local field and approximate them arbitrarily closely by elements of your global field. I think there will be a Krasner's Lemma phenomenon where if you get close enough the reductive group will be unchanged.

Comment: @WillSawin: I think you will have a hard time proving that your approximation is a group to begin with. Would you care to provide a complete argument?

Comment: The easiest case, where $G$ is semisimple (and either adjoint or simply connected) and $K$ has characteristic 0, was proved by Borel and Harder [J. Reine Angew. Math. 298 (1978) 53-64], by showing the natural map of Galois cohomology sets $H^1(F, \mathrm{Aut}G) \to H^1(K,\mathrm{Aut}G)$ is surjective if $G$ is absolutely almost simple. (In fact, they allow any finite set of places of $F$ on the right-hand side, instead of only one completion.) Section 3 of the Borel-Harder paper seems to prove a similar result for groups of type $A$ in positive characteristic, and perhaps can be generalized.

Comment: @QuestionMark - Deform the coefficients of the polynomials giving the group structure as well, and remember all the relations among the coefficients coming from the associativity and other relations. These variables and relations define an algebraic variety - take a point of that variety defined over a global field which approximates your local field point. This is easy because points defined over the algebraic closure of the global field are dense, both in the Zariski sense and over the local field. That's not the hard part. I don't know how to do the rest, so I can't post a complete answer.

Comment: Yes, by inner twisting one can reduce to the problem of algebraizing torsors for any smooth affine group over any henselian valued field whatsoever. This requires no input from number theory or serious algebraic geometry at all.  I'll post a complete proof later, when I find time. I do not believe that the method suggested by Will can be turned into a proof; it seems too soft.

Comment: @WillSawin: As far as I can tell, either your variety parametrizing groups is defined over a local field and you have no global model, so it makes no sense to talk of global points, or, once you have deformed the coefficients that give "the associativity and other relations," you no longer have an initial local point to approximate by global points. My feeling is the same as that of user74230: this won't work (even to get a global model of $G$ as a group).

Comment: @DaveWitteMorris: the result you mention proves a much stronger conclusion (in particular that adjoint/simply connected semisimple groups are $\mathbf{Q}$-definable). But this stronger conclusion is not true for arbitrary semisimple connected groups over $\mathbf{Q}_p$. For the question I would tend to believe that the material in Borel-Serre's 1964 paper "Theoremes de finitude en Cohomologie Galoisienne" answer the question (at least in char. 0).

Comment: @QuestionMark Just take the variety of all affine algebraic groups embedded in some affine space by equations of bounded degree.  This is defined over $\mathbb Z$, and has a local point. The problem is that I don't know an appropriate continuity statement. As user74230 points out, if you avoid this enormous space of groups and just focus on the space of groups in $GL_n$ that are conjugate, over an algebraically closed field, to $H$, you get continuity using the implicit function theorem.

Comment: @WillSawin: I don't see why the "variety of all affine algebraic groups" under some bounded degree should have the requisite smoothness properties to apply the implicit function theorem (and the latter over what?).

Comment: @user74230 I am saying precisely that your method avoids this space, allowing you to use the implicit function theorem, whereas my method doesn't work. I know better now than to argue with you. I never claimed that my method works - if it was a complete proof, I would post it as an answer - merely that it doesn't fail for the reason Question Mark says.

Comment: @WillSawin: Thanks for the explanation. Now your approach makes more sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, @YCor -- I didn't know whether $\mathbb{Q}$ would always work. For semisimple groups in characteristic 0, Borel-Harder says the universal cover of $\mathbf{G}$ can be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. I think it is easy to see by Galois theory that the kernel of the isogeny to $\mathbf{G}$ is defined over some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that is contained in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ (since we are in characteristic 0), so I don't think any Galois cohomology is needed besides Borel-Harder. (PS The same argument can also glue a semisimple group to a torus, so the two cases can be treated separately.)

Comment: Correction: Instead of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, I should have said $K$, the local field (of characteristic 0) over which we know the kernel is defined. (Being defined over $K$ is the same as being invariant under $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$, which is why I don't think Galois cohomology is needed.)

Comment: @user74230 Is there any reference for your result I can use in one of my preprints? If there is not, I kindly ask your permission to state your proof. In order to do so, it would be nice to have your full name. You can also contact me via email. Thanks for the argument and kind regards!

Comment: @TimoRicharz: I don't know any reference, since I'd never heard of or thought about this result in such generality before seeing the question posed here. I'll email you at Bonn now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pick a global field $E$ and finite place $w$ with $E_w=K$. The fraction field $k$ over $E$ of the henselization of the "algebraic" local ring at $w$ is the direct limit of finite separable sub extensions $F/E$ for which the place $v$ on $F$ from the valuation on $k$ satisfies $F_v=K$. Thus, it suffices to "algebraize" $G$ over $k$. We therefore forget about number field and focus on a henselian valued field $k$ with completion denoted $K$ and aim to descend a connected reductive $K$-group $G$ to a connected reductive $k$-group.

The Galois groups of $k$ and $K$ are naturally isomorphic, so if $R$ denotes the root datum of $G_{K_s}$ then ${\rm{H}}^1(k, {\rm{Aut}}(R)) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(K, {\rm{Aut}}(R))$ is bijective. This says that every quasi-split connected reductive $K$-group descends to a quasi-split connected reductive $k$-group which is moreover unique up to isomorphism (since these H$^1$'s classify quasi-split forms with a given geometric root datum). Every connected reductive $K$-group $G$ has a (unique) quasi-split inner form $G_0$, so $G$ is obtained from $G_0$ via twisting against a class in ${\rm{H}}^1(K, G_0^{\rm{ad}})$ for the adjoint semisimple $G_0^{\rm{ad}} := G_0/Z_{G_0}$. Thus, it suffices to show that ${\rm{H}}^1(k, H) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(K,H_K)$ is surjective for every smooth connected affine $k$-group $H$ (such as $H$ being the quasi-split $k$-descent of $G_0^{\rm{ad}}$).  Even better:

**Theorem**: For any smooth affine $k$-group $H$, the natural map
$${\rm{H}}^1(k,H) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(K,H)$$
is bijective.

Proof: By Galois-twisting, injectivity reduces to triviality of the kernel. 
In other words, if $E$ is an $H$-torsor over $k$ which has a $K$-point then it has a $k$-point.  More generally, if
$X$ is a smooth $k$-scheme then $X(k)$ is dense in $X(K)$ for the valuation topoloy.  This is Zariski-local on $X$, so
we can assume there is an etale map $f:X \rightarrow \mathbf{A}^n_k$.  The open image $V=f(X)$ is dense open in $\mathbf{A}^n_k$, so
$V(k)$ is dense in $V(K)$ due to density of $k$ in $K$.  By the Zariski-local structure theorem for etale morphisms and the $K$-analytic inverse
function theorem, for each $x \in X(K)$ and $v=f(x)\in V(K)$, every $v'$ sufficiently near $v$ admits $x'\in f^{-1}(v')$ near $x$ in $X(K)$.  By openness of $X(K) \rightarrow V(K)$, for any $x \in X(K)$ and open $\Omega \subset X(K)$ around $x$ we can find an open $U \subset V(K)$ around $v=f(x)$ such that every 
$u \in U$ is the image of a $K$-point in $\Omega$.  Consider such $u \in V(k) \cap U$ (as exists by density of $V(k)$ in $V(K)$). The fiber scheme $f^{-1}(u)$ is finite etale over $k$, so the equivalence of Galois theories of $k$ and $K$ shows that every $K$-point in $f^{-1}(u)$ comes from a unique $k$-point of $f^{-1}(u)$. Hence, we can find a $k$-point in $\Omega$.  This completes the proof of injectivity.

For surjectivity, choose a closed $k$-subgroup inclusion $j:H \hookrightarrow {\rm{GL}}_n:=G$ and let $X=G/H$ (a smooth $k$-scheme).  Thus, there is a natural surjection
$$G(k)\backslash X(k) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(k,H)$$
and likewise for $K$ (since ${\rm{H}}^1(k, {\rm{GL}}_n)=1$ and likewise for $K$).  It therefore suffices to show that the natural map
$$X(k) \rightarrow G(K) \backslash X(K)$$
is surjective.  Since $X(k)$ is dense in $X(K)$ by the above, it suffices to show that all $G(K)$-orbits in $X(K)$ are open.  But
each orbit map $G_K \rightarrow X_K$ through a $K$-point is a smooth map since $H$ is smooth, so the induced map on $K$-points is open (hence has open image) by
the $K$-analytic implicit function theorem (using the Zariski-local structure of smooth morphisms).

QED

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer your question completely, but this extended comment may be helpful.
Probably the answer will be "yes", judging at least from the old classification by Tits summarized in the proceedings of the 1965 AMS Summer Institute at Boulder (published by AMS in 1966 as vol. 9 in their series *Proc. of Symposia in Pure Math.*, which was for a while freely available at the AMS website).    Tits was interested in sorting out the possible forms of a simple algebraic group over various kinds of fields, and in his summary tables one sees case-by-case that existence of a group defined over what he calls a "$\mathfrak{p}$-adic" field implies existence of such a group over some number field (but not vice versa).   He also provides some general theorems in arbitrary characteristic, with proofs later filled in and somewhat corrected in thesis work by his student Martin Selbach at Bonn (1976).  But it may be impossible to find a complete treatment anywhere in the literature.  (Will's comment is worth following up.)

P.S. It's worth adding that a typical (connected) reductive group is an almost-direct product of an algebraic torus with one or more simple algebraic groups.   In particular, you'd want to look separately at the case of a torus.